# If $X:\Omega\to\Omega'$ and $f:\Omega'\to\Omega''$ are measurable and $f$ is injective, then $\sigma(X)=\sigma(f\circ X)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ and $(\Omega'',\mathcal{A}'')$ be measurable spaces
- $X:\Omega\to\Omega'$ be $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{A}'$-measurable
- $f:\Omega'\to\Omega''$ be $\mathcal{A}'$-$\mathcal{A}''$-measurable and injective

I want to show that $$\sigma(X)=\sigma(f\circ X)$$

---

We've got $$\sigma(X)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\left\{X^{-1}(A):A\in\mathcal{A}'\right\}\stackrel{(1)}{=}\left\{X^{-1}(A):A\in\left.\mathcal{A}'\right|_{X(\Omega)}\right\}$$

where $(1)$ should hold since each $A\in\mathcal{A}'$ can be written in the form $$A=B\cup C\;\;\;\text{with }B\in\left.\mathcal{A}'\right|_{X(\Omega)},C\in\mathcal{A}'\setminus\left.\mathcal{A}'\right|_{X(\Omega)}$$ and $$X^{-1}(A)=X^{-1}(B\cup C)=X^{-1}(B)\cup\underbrace{X^{-1}(C)}_{=\emptyset}$$ I've got problems to proceed. How exactly do we need to use the injectivity of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injectivity of $f$ implies that $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ for each $A\in\mathcal A'$ so that the sets $X^{-1}(A)$, i.e. elements of $\sigma(X)$ can be written as $X^{-1}(f^{-1}(f(A)))=(f\circ X)^{-1}(f(A))$ wich are elements of $\sigma(f\circ X)$ if $f(A)\in\mathcal A''$

However,  $A\in\mathcal A'$ combined with measurability of $f$ does not ensure that $f(A)\in\mathcal A''$ (see my comment).

So my answer is not complete.

---

**Edit** (to complete my answer)

Under these conditions statement $\sigma(X)=\sigma(f\circ X)$ is not true in general.

Counterexample:

Let $\Omega=\Omega'=\Omega''$ and $\mathcal A=\mathcal A'$. Let $f$ and $X$ both be the identity on $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal A'':=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Then $f$ and $X$ are both measurable, and this with $\sigma(X)=\mathcal A$ and $\sigma(f\circ X)=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$. Also $f$ is bijective (hence injective).

However $\mathcal A$ can be properly finer than $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$.

Comment: What if $f$ would be bijective?

Comment: If $\Omega'=\Omega''$ and $\mathcal A''$ is a proper subset of $\mathcal A'$ and $f$ is the (bijective) identity, then it is measurable but we can find  a set $A\in\mathcal A'$ with $f(A)=A\notin\mathcal A''$.